# Is it possible to create a Stack Overflow CV that is visible only to potential new employers (in Stack Overflow Careers) and hidden to general public?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Two questions:

1. Is it possible to create a Stack Overflow CV that is visible only to potential new employers (which subscribed to Stack Overflow Careers only) and not visible to the general public?

   Example: A developer wants to have some control/privacy, or avoid spam robots crawling their CV and display its content without their consent in other websites not belonging to the SO network.

   Notes: Could you please point me out a page describing how SO protect our privacy in this case, and what are the options available to developers?
2. Is it possible to not allow showing a Stack Overflow CV to a specific employer if they have subscribed to Stack Overflow Careers?

   Example: A developer is interested in seeking some new opportunities, but they do not want their current employer to know about it.

Comment: How would one define a **potential employer**, can't your boss then just easily sign up as a so-called potential employer and see your info?

Comment: @AtaKeskin Maybe it could be defined as somebody who posts job offers in SO Jobs. I think they have to pay for that, so the CV wouldn't be available to the general public.

Comment: The short answer is this functionality is NOT there.  To avoid this do not make your CV public unless someone asks you for it.

Comment: @Oriol well you could always remove the private info from your CV and present them to the **"potential employer"** when asked. like JonH stated

Answer (score 6):

One partial solution to this, which I use, is to rename the names of your educational and work institutions to generic equivalents, such as:

- UK University
- FinTech Startup
- Large Logistics Company
- Solo Project

This has the advantage that even if I lose control of my data, prospective employers or recruiters cannot unscrupulously call people in my employment and educational history in order to obtain information about me. If an employer is serious, we can have a proper conversation before they get an emailed/paper copy of my CV.

You also do not need to use your real name in your Stack Overflow CV.

I do tend to use links to my blog, and other profiles on the web, but I do not really treat those as a potential privacy violation.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange has recently updated its TOS policy to prevent this [as of April 19].

Here is the [official] announcement: [A Terms of Service update restricting companies that scrape your profile information without your permission](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/a-terms-of-service-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-informa)